# For fixed $t_0$ and $s<t$, what's $E(1_{t>t_0}\mid \mathcal{F}_s)$

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Let $\{\mathcal{F}_s\}$ be a filtration.

For fixed $t_0$ and $s<t$, what's $E(1_{t>t_0}\mid \mathcal{F}_s)$?

And what about $E(1_{t<t_0}\mid \mathcal{F}_s)$?

Edit: I'll edit in my motivation in case it's important.

I was trying to prove that $B_{\min(t,t_0)}$ (where $B_t$ is a brownian motion) is a Martingale, for a fixed $t_0$.

I tried to separate using indicator functions, and in one of the terms I have: $E(B_{t_0}1_{t>t_0}\mid \mathcal{F}_s)$. So, I was thinking that the indicator functions are simply independent. If so, then I would have $E(B_{t_0}\mid \mathcal{F}_s)1_{t>t_0}$. Now, however, I have problem. In the case of $s<t_0$, then $E(B_{t_0}\mid \mathcal{F}_s)=B_s$, which is something I don't want...

Comment: Are $t_0$ and $t$ both deterministic?  If so, this is just a conditional expectation of a constant

Comment: @user6247850 Hi, thanks for the comment. Both are deterministic. I've added my motivation. I'm interested in knowing better the behaviour of the indicator function, individually, and together with a Brownian motion...

Comment: @user6247850 if you could add some pointers related to my motivation, written above, I would also appreciate it. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just let $t \geq s$ and calculate

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E} \left [B_{t \wedge t_{0}}\, | \, \mathcal{F}_{s} \right ]
&= \mathbb{E} \left [B_{t} \mathcal{1}_{t \leq t_{0}} \, | \, \mathcal{F}_{s} \right ] + \mathbb{E} \left [B_{t_{0}} \mathcal{1}_{t > t_{0}} \, | \, \mathcal{F}_{s} \right ] \\
&\overset{(i)}{=} \mathcal{1}_{t \leq t_{0}} \mathbb{E}[B_{t} \, | \, \mathcal{F}_{s}] + \mathcal{1}_{t > t_{0}} \mathbb{E}[B_{t_{0}} \, | \, \mathcal{F}_{s} ] \\
&= \mathcal{1}_{t \leq t_{0}} B_{s} + \mathcal{1}_{t > t_{0}} B_{s \wedge t_{0}} \\
&\overset{(ii)}{=} \mathcal{1}_{t \leq t_{0}} B_{s \wedge t_{0}} + \mathcal{1}_{t > t_{0}} B_{s \wedge t_{0}} \\
&= B_{s \wedge t_{0}}.
\end{align*}

Note that step $(ii)$ follows since if $t_{0}<s$ then $t \geq s > t_{0}$ by assumption and so $1_{t \leq t_{0}} = 0$.

Step $(i)$ follows since $\mathcal{1}_{t \leq t_{0}}(\omega) \equiv \mathcal{1}_{t \leq t_{0}}$ is deterministic and so is $\mathcal{F}_{s} = \sigma(B_{u} \, | u \leq s ) \, $-measurable. In fact, $\mathcal{1}_{t \leq t_{0}}$  is $\mathcal{F}_{0} = \sigma(B_{0}) = \{\emptyset,\Omega \}$-measurable. For example, if say $t$ (which is fixed) is $\leq t_{0}$, then either $\mathcal{1}_{t \leq t_{0}}^{-1}(B) = \Omega$ (if $1 \in B$) and $\mathcal{1}_{t \leq t_{0}}^{-1}(B) = \emptyset$ (if $1 \notin B$).

Feel free to ask if there are any questions.

Comment: Many thanks Christopher! Now I get where I did the 'wrong turn' +1 ;)

Comment: No worries! Glad to help!